# Can't load ajax data onto bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I have a datatable which gets its data from an AJAX source and works great. The problem I'm having is I want to click the table get the id for the row clicked and then open a bootstrap modal with the data.

It works great when I copy the script into Chrome's console, but when I try to include it in the file like the code below my modal is empty. Its weird because my console is showing my the same output as when it does work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Hello</title>
      <!-- Core CSS - Include with every page -->
      <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- Page-Level Plugin CSS - Tables -->
      <link href="dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- SB Admin CSS - Include with every page -->
      <link href="sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="wrapper">
         <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
            <div class="navbar-header">
               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".sidebar-collapse">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
               <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Hello</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-header -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
               <li class="dropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                  <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                  </a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-messages">
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">
                           <div>
                              <strong>John Smith</strong>
                              <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                              <em>Yesterday</em>
                              </span>
                           </div>
                           <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
                        </a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="divider"></li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">
                           <div>
                              <strong>John Smith</strong>
                              <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                              <em>Yesterday</em>
                              </span>
                           </div>
                           <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
                        </a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="divider"></li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">
                           <div>
                              <strong>John Smith</strong>
                              <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                              <em>Yesterday</em>
                              </span>
                           </div>
                           <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
                        </a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="divider"></li>
                     <li>
                        <a class="text-center" href="#">
                        <strong>Read All Messages</strong>
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                        </a>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
                  <!-- /.dropdown-messages -->
               </li>
               <!-- /.dropdown -->
               <li class="dropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                  <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                  </a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-tasks">
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">
                           <div>
                              <p>
                                 <strong>Task 1</strong>
                                 <span class="pull-right text-muted">40% Complete</span>
                              </p>
                              <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                 <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
                                    <span class="sr-only">40% Complete (success)</span>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="divider"></li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">
                           <div>
                              <p>
                                 <strong>Task 2</strong>
                                 <span class="pull-right text-muted">20% Complete</span>
                              </p>
                              <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                 <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 20%">
                                    <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="divider"></li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">
                           <div>
                              <p>
                                 <strong>Task 3</strong>
                                 <span class="pull-right text-muted">60% Complete</span>
                              </p>
                              <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                 <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%">
                                    <span class="sr-only">60% Complete (warning)</span>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="divider"></li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">
                           <div>
                              <p>
                                 <strong>Task 4</strong>
                                 <span class="pull-right text-muted">80% Complete</span>
                              </p>
                              <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                 <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%">
                                    <span class="sr-only">80% Complete (danger)</span>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="divider"></li>
                     <li>
                        <a class="text-center" href="#">
                        <strong>See All Tasks</strong>
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                        </a>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
                  <!-- /.dropdown-tasks -->
               </li>
               <!-- /.dropdown -->
               <li class="dropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                  <i class="fa fa-bell fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                  </a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-alerts">
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">
                           <div>
                              <i class="fa fa-comment fa-fw"></i> New Comment
                              <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                           </div>
                        </a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="divider"></li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">
                           <div>
                              <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i> 3 New Followers
                              <span class="pull-right text-muted small">12 minutes ago</span>
                           </div>
                        </a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="divider"></li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">
                           <div>
                              <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i> Message Sent
                              <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                           </div>
                        </a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="divider"></li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">
                           <div>
                              <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i> New Task
                              <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                           </div>
                        </a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="divider"></li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">
                           <div>
                              <i class="fa fa-upload fa-fw"></i> Server Rebooted
                              <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                           </div>
                        </a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="divider"></li>
                     <li>
                        <a class="text-center" href="#">
                        <strong>See All Alerts</strong>
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                        </a>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
                  <!-- /.dropdown-alerts -->
               </li>
               <!-- /.dropdown -->
               <li class="dropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                  <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                  </a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> User Profile</a>
                     </li>
                     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-fw"></i> Settings</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="divider"></li>
                     <li><a href="/logout"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
                  <!-- /.dropdown-user -->
               </li>
               <!-- /.dropdown -->
            </ul>
            <!-- /.navbar-top-links -->
            <div class="navbar-default navbar-static-side" role="navigation">
               <div class="sidebar-collapse">
                  <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                     <li class="sidebar-search">
                        <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                           <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                           <span class="input-group-btn">
                           <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                           <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                           </button>
                           </span>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /input-group -->
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="/"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</a>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Charts<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                           <li>
                              <a href="/flot">Flot Charts</a>
                           </li>
                           <li>
                              <a href="/morris">Morris.js Charts</a>
                           </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="/tables"><i class="fa fa-table fa-fw"></i> Tables</a>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="/technicians"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Technicians</a>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="/cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Cart</a>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="/forms"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> Forms</a>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> UI Elements<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                           <li>
                              <a href="/panels-wells">Panels and Wells</a>
                           </li>
                           <li>
                              <a href="/buttons">Buttons</a>
                           </li>
                           <li>
                              <a href="/notifications">Notifications</a>
                           </li>
                           <li>
                              <a href="/typography">Typography</a>
                           </li>
                           <li>
                              <a href="/grid">Grid</a>
                           </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sitemap fa-fw"></i> Multi-Level Dropdown<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                           <li>
                              <a href="#">Second Level Item</a>
                           </li>
                           <li>
                              <a href="#">Second Level Item</a>
                           </li>
                           <li>
                              <a href="#">Third Level <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                              <ul class="nav nav-third-level">
                                 <li>
                                    <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                 </li>
                                 <li>
                                    <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                 </li>
                                 <li>
                                    <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                 </li>
                                 <li>
                                    <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                 </li>
                              </ul>
                              <!-- /.nav-third-level -->
                           </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-files-o fa-fw"></i> Sample Pages<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                           <li>
                              <a href="/blank">Blank Page</a>
                           </li>
                           <li>
                              <a href="/login">Login Page</a>
                           </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                     </li>
                  </ul>
                  <!-- /#side-menu -->
               </div>
               <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
         </nav>
         <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-lg-12">
                  <h1 class="page-header">Tables</h1>
               </div>
               <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
            </div>
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
               <div class="modal-dialog">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                     <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Order Details</h4>
                     </div>
                     <div class="modal-body">
                        ...
                     </div>
                     <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-lg-12">
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                     <div class="panel-heading">
                        Workorders
                     </div>
                     <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                     <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                           <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                              <thead>
                                 <tr>
                                    <th>_id</th>
                                    <th>Phone #</th>
                                    <th>Sub Area</th>
                                    <th>Due By</th>
                                    <th>City</th>
                                    <th>State</th>
                                 </tr>
                              </thead>
                           </table>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <!-- /.panel-body -->
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.panel -->
               </div>
               <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
            <!-- /.row -->
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-lg-12">
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                     <div class="panel-heading">
                        Products
                     </div>
                     <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                     <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                           <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example2">
                              <thead>
                                 <tr>
                                    <th>Product</th>
                                    <th>Category</th>
                                    <th>Price</th>
                                 </tr>
                              </thead>
                           </table>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <!-- /.panel-body -->
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.panel -->
               </div>
               <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- /#page-wrapper -->
      </div>
      <!-- /#wrapper -->
      <!-- Core Scripts - Include with every page -->
      <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>
      <!-- Page-Level Plugin Scripts - Tables -->
      <script src="jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
      <script src="dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
      <!-- SB Admin Scripts - Include with every page -->
      <script src="sb-admin.js"></script>
      <!-- -->
      <script src="mustache.js"></script>
      <!-- Page-Level Demo Scripts - Tables - Use for reference -->
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
             $('#dataTables-example').dataTable( {
                 "processing": true,
                 "oScroller": {
                     "loadingIndicator": true
                 },
                 "oColVis": {
                   "activate": "mouseover",
                 },
                 "aaSorting": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
                 // "bServerSide": true,
                 // "bJQueryUI": true,
                 // "bStateSave": true,
                 "ajax": "/workordersjson",
                 "columns": [
                     { "data": "_id" },
                     { "data": "Phone #" },
                     { "data": "Sub Area" },
                     { "data": "Due By" },
                     { "data": "City" },
                     { "data": "State" }
                 ]
             } );
         } );

             $('#dataTables-example2').dataTable( {
                 "processing": true,
                 "oScroller": {
                     "loadingIndicator": true
                 },
                 "oColVis": {
                   "activate": "mouseover",
                 },
                 "aaSorting": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
                 // "bServerSide": true,
                 // "bJQueryUI": true,
                 // "bStateSave": true,
                 "ajax": "/productsjson2",
                 "columns": [
                     { "data": "value" },
                     { "data": "category" },
                     { "data": "price" },
                 ]
             } );



      </script>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
             $('#dataTables-example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function(event){
                     event.preventDefault();                    

                     var nTds = $('td', this);
                     //example to show any cell data can be gathered, I used to get my ID from the first coumn in my final code
                     var sBrowser = $(nTds[0]).text();
                     var sGrade = $(nTds[4]).text();
                     var dialogText="The info cell I need was in (col2) as:"+sBrowser+" and in (col5) as:"+sGrade+"" ;
                     var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href");
                     console.log(sBrowser);
                    $.getJSON('/workorder/'+sBrowser, function(data) {
                     console.log(data);
                     var template = "<table class=table><thead><tr><th>Line</th><th>Product</th><th>Status</thead><tbody></tbody<tr></tr>{{#lines}}<td>{{Line #}}</td><td>{{Product}}</td><td>{{Status}}</td><tr>{{/lines}}</table>";
                     var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
                     $('.modal-body').html(html);
                     $('#myModal').modal()
         });
         });
         })
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i can't find '#dataTables-example tbody' on your html.

Comment: I updated to '#dataTables-example' and still get empty modal when including code on file ;(

Comment: are you sure the function on click isn't getting called before rending the data to dom? try putting your onlick function after the  rendering dataTable.

Comment: I thought by including it after in code it would load after. Is that not the case? If not how do I correct it? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Loading the script in a separate file did the trick.

Comment: Hi @fpena06. Your question was automatically flagged by the Stack Overflow system as being excessively long. This adds a huge barrier to people answering your question, as it's hard to pinpoint exactly where the problem is. In future, you might want to consider making a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make your question shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to put the scripts after each one or on a separate file and place them in order in html.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
                 $('#dataTables-example').dataTable( {
                     "processing": true,
                     "oScroller": {
                         "loadingIndicator": true
                     },
                     "oColVis": {
                       "activate": "mouseover",
                     },
                     "aaSorting": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
                     // "bServerSide": true,
                     // "bJQueryUI": true,
                     // "bStateSave": true,
                     "ajax": "/workordersjson",
                     "columns": [
                         { "data": "_id" },
                         { "data": "Phone #" },
                         { "data": "Sub Area" },
                         { "data": "Due By" },
                         { "data": "City" },
                         { "data": "State" }
                     ]
                 } );
             } );

                 $('#dataTables-example2').dataTable( {
                     "processing": true,
                     "oScroller": {
                         "loadingIndicator": true
                     },
                     "oColVis": {
                       "activate": "mouseover",
                     },
                     "aaSorting": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
                     // "bServerSide": true,
                     // "bJQueryUI": true,
                     // "bStateSave": true,
                     "ajax": "/productsjson2",
                     "columns": [
                         { "data": "value" },
                         { "data": "category" },
                         { "data": "price" },
                     ]
                 } );
 $('#dataTables-example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function(event){
                     event.preventDefault();                    

                     var nTds = $('td', this);
                     //example to show any cell data can be gathered, I used to get my ID from the first coumn in my final code
                     var sBrowser = $(nTds[0]).text();
                     var sGrade = $(nTds[4]).text();
                     var dialogText="The info cell I need was in (col2) as:"+sBrowser+" and in (col5) as:"+sGrade+"" ;
                     var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href");
                     console.log(sBrowser);
                    $.getJSON('/workorder/'+sBrowser, function(data) {
                     console.log(data);
                     var template = "<table class=table><thead><tr><th>Line</th><th>Product</th><th>Status</thead><tbody></tbody<tr></tr>{{#lines}}<td>{{Line #}}</td><td>{{Product}}</td><td>{{Status}}</td><tr>{{/lines}}</table>";
                     var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
                     $('.modal-body').html(html);
                     $('#myModal').modal()
         });
         });
         })
)}
```